# Constraining a generic parameter

Tags: generics, swift

I have a protocol called `Machine`. It has a `typealias` for the input it can read. It's constrained to be a `Hashable` type.

```
protocol Machine {

    typealias InputType: Hashable

    // ...

}
```

There is a class that implements this protocol called `OrMachine`.

```
class OrMachine<T: Hashable>: Machine {

}
```

I'd like to make an initialiser that takes in an array of `Machine` objects. Because machine contains a `typealias` I have to define it as a generic parameter to the method that implements `Machine`. I also need to say that the Machines that are passed have the same input type as this one.

```
init<MachineType: Machine where MachineType.InputType == T>(machines: [MachineType]){

}
```

This gives me the following error.

> Same-type constraint type 'T' does not conform to required protocol 'Hashable'

Why does this happen? In `OrMachine` I clearly say that `T` implements `Hashable`.
Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried

    init<T: Hashable, MachineType: Machine where MachineType.InputType == T>(machines: [MachineType]){
        
    }

Comment: @TomErikStøwer `T` is already declared as `Hashable` in the enclosing `class` type.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it seems to get rid of the error. Perhaps type constraining done in the class declaration is not inherited by the next level of type declaration done in the init method?

Comment: Definitely a bug.  I filed a radar for you.

Comment: I built it all cleanly and it reproduced. Sorry for the earlier confusion.

Comment: The one trouble with @TomErikStøwer's answer is that I don't think it constrains the way you mean to. It may be creating a new `T` unrelated to the enclosing `T` (so it would accept any Hashable, not just the one tied to this class). Haven't tested, but something to watch out for.

Comment: That could very well be true. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @TomErikStøwer This is definitely the case. Adding `T` to the method declaration will create a new type.